# Do abstract subclasses of an abstract superclass violate LSP?

Tags: oop, inheritance, uml, class-design, liskov-substitution-principle

I'm working with SOLID principles, specifically Liskov's Substitution Principle (LSP).

I have an abstract class called `Button` that defines different methods and different subclasses extend it to define some of those methods. For example I have a subclass called `PauseButton` that implement only 3 methods from the abstract class.

Is that concidered a violation of LSP?

Comment: This is probably helpful: https://www.tomdalling.com/blog/software-design/solid-class-design-the-liskov-substitution-principle/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core idea of [Liskov's Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) is that you could use instances of the subtype whenever you may use instances of the type. The subtype may be more specialized but it should comply with the same contract.

In your example, `PauseButton` fulfills LSP with regard to `Button` if all its "methods" (we say "operations" in UML) comply with the contract defined for `Button`.  It's not just about implementing the methods but making sure that the methods are compatible:

1. `PauseButton` may not strengthen the preconditions of `Button`.  I.e.  if the conditions are fulfilled to perform a `Button` method, you should be able to perform the corresonding `PauseButton` method as well.
2. `PauseButton` may not weaken the postconditions of `Button`.  I.e. if `Button` makes some promises about a method,  `PauseButton` must fulfill at least the same promises.
3. Invariants of `Button` (logical conditions that should be always true) should also be invariants of `PauseButton`.  `PauseButton` may have additional invariants.
4. History constraint: roughly speaking, it means that whereas `PauseButton` is a `Button`,   `PauseButton` methods should not modify directly its `Button` state, without using methods of the `Button`.  No shortcut.

In the case of abstract subclasses, it's more delicate to verify LSP since we cannot look at direct instances.  Nevertheless, the subclasses could be indirectly instantiated by concrete subclasses that provide the missing methods:

- If at least one of the three `PauseButton` methods that you implement infringes LSP (i.e. are incompatible with the same method from `Button`),  then  `PauseButton` violates LSP.
- But if all the three methods are compliant,  and if `PauseButton` does not redefine the contract of the other methods,  you can assume that `PauseButton` is LSP-Compliant : you could create a concrete subclass of `PauseButton` that would be compliant, even if at the present stage such sublass doesn't exist.  This fulfills the requirements for interchangeability.